# Memory allocation c++

Tags: c++

I have a problem with memory allocation, when running the following while loop the occupied RAM of my computer continue to increase, I don't understand what I have to allocate and how to do it

```
while(cvWaitKey(1)<0)
{  
    img = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    height = img->height;         
    width = img->width;           
    step = img->widthStep;          
    channels = img->nChannels;  
    gray_arr = (uchar * * )malloc(sizeof(uchar * )*(height + 1));
    for(int i=0; i<height; i++)
        {
            gray_arr[i] = (uchar * )malloc(sizeof(uchar)*(width + 1));
            for(int j=0; j<width; j++)
                {
                    gray_arr[i][j] = (0.11*data[i*step + j*channels] + 0.56*data[i*step + j*channels + 1] + 0.33*data[i*step + j*channels + 2]);
                }
        }
                    for(int j=0; j<width; j++)
                    {
                       sum=0;
                       for(int i=first_pixel; i<last_pixel+1; i++)
                       {
                       value= gray_arr[i][j];
                       sum = sum + value;
                       }
                       sum=sum/sample_number; 
                       store[j]= sum;
                     }
        for(int i=0; i<width; i++)
        {
           intensity_inv[i]=270- store[i];
        }
        graph = cvCreateImage(cvSize(1280,300),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
        cvRectangle(graph, cvPoint(256,0), cvPoint(255,1), CV_RGB(255,255,255),1);
        for (int i=0; i<width; i++)
        {
            cvLine(graph,cvPoint(i,270),cvPoint(i,intensity_inv[i]),CV_RGB(0,0,0)); 
        }
cvNamedWindow("Sp",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cvMoveWindow("Sp",0,550);
cvNamedWindow("Original Image", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
cvMoveWindow("Original Image", 500, 0);
cvShowImage("Original Image", img);
cvShowImage("Sp",graph);
free(gray_arr); 
}
```

Sorry for my bad english

Thanks

Comment: Off the bat, I see `height + 1` calls to `malloc`, but only one call to `free`. There should eventually be a `free` call for every `malloc` call; if there isn't, you are leaking memory.

Comment: BTW: This looks like C, not C++.

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` ( which is "old" C ) instead of `new` ( which is C++ )? And please format your code better ( consistent indentation, empty lines, etc )

Comment: I didn't know that...I'm a novice, I found that code in an example and I adapted it for my application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling malloc for the `gray_arr` array:

```
gray_arr = (uchar * * )malloc(sizeof(uchar * )*(height + 1));
```

and also for elements within that array:

```
gray_arr[i] = (uchar * )malloc(sizeof(uchar)*(width + 1));
```

However, you're only calling `free` for the allocation of the entire array. You need to also free up the allocation of each element.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that worked! But the RAM is still, slowly, increasing...there should be something else...

Comment: Where did you put your "free"?

Comment: At the end of the loop...I added this:      for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
   {
    free(gray_arr[i]);
   }
   free(gray_arr);